# Can one do incremental backups from a server with Filezilla (how?)

Tags: backup, filezilla, incremental-backup

Can one do incremental backups from a server with Filezilla and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can do it with filezilla.

You could look at rsync if you just want to copy over the files that are new/changed.
It is on all the linux distros, and I think there is also a couple windows ports.

If you are using windows, I am not sure if the rsync client can run in server mode to receive the files. If you are using linux, then you are all set.

Comment: yet another reason to use Total Commander :)

Comment: Hmmm. I might look into that. I do dual-boot Ubuntu (9.10 at the moment)...